# Merging separate SQL query results into one output as columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get the last 10, 5 etc OrderReference for a specific CustomerID and can do this with multiple queries. The OrderReferences are unique and in sequential order at time of creation so to get the last instances i've used Top and Desc functions.

How would I combine these queries to produce the output as separate columns within the same result set though?

E.g. the queries I have are:

```
Select top 10 OrderReference
from Orders
where CustomerID = '123456'
order by OrderReference desc

Select top 5 OrderReference
from Orders
where CustomerID = '123456'
order by OrderReference desc
```

The output I need would be:

```
OrderReference | OrderReference 
---------------+----------------    
Ref1           | Ref1
Ref2           | Ref2
Ref3           | Ref3
Ref4           | Ref4 
Ref5           | Ref5 
Ref6           |   
Ref7           |   
Ref8           |    
Ref9           |    
Ref10          |
```

Thanks

Comment: Your two queries are identical.  Is this intentional?

Comment: And tag the dbms you're using. (Those queries are product specific.)

Comment: Queries now amended

Answer (score 0):

If i have understood correct, this could be achieved in a CTE:

```
DECLARE @cust_id AS CHAR(6)
SET @Cust_id = '123456';

WITH Top10 AS
(Select top 10 OrderReference from Orders where CustomerID = @Cust_id order by OrderReference desc ),
Top5 AS
(Select top 5 OrderReference from Orders where CustomerID = @Cust_id order by OrderReference desc)

SELECT *
FROM Top10 
LEFT JOIN Top5 ON Top10.OrderReference = Top5.OrderReference
```

Comment: I get the following error when running the query

Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'.

Comment: Apologies, i had not put a semi-colon `;` after setting the variable. I've amended my answer.

Comment: It's not recognising the CustomerID column now

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'customerID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'CustomerID '.

Comment: @TheFault - The CTE join will need changing from CustomerID to OrderReference. Sorry i'm half asleep this morning. I've amended my answer.

Comment: Mark this as the answer please, so the the question is completed.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION ALL` this will solve your problem

```
SELECT TOP 10 OrderReference FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = '123456' ORDER BY OrderReference DESC 
UNION ALL 
SELECT TOP 5 OrderReference FROM Orders WHERE CustomerID = '123456' ORDER BY OrderReference DESC
```

Comment: This will return 15 rows of data which is not what the OP is looking for. They want 10 rows with two columns.